# Fail to compile with Go (Ubuntu)

Tags: go, github, compilation, prometheus, openvpn

I'm trying to install OpenVPN exporter for Prometheus, anyway I've downloaded the exporter to my desktop, added that dir to my $GOPATH path and whenver I try to run:

```
go build -o openvpn_exporter main.go
```

I receive the message:

```
src/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/desc.go:22:2: cannot find package "github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2 (from $GOROOT)
        /home/ubuntu/openvpn_exporter-0.3.0/src/github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2 (from $GOPATH)
src/google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protowire/wire.go:15:2: cannot find package "math/bits" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/math/bits (from $GOROOT)
        /home/ubuntu/openvpn_exporter-0.3.0/src/math/bits (from $GOPATH)
src/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp/instrument_client.go:19:2: cannot find package "net/http/httptrace" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/httptrace (from $GOROOT)
        /home/ubuntu/openvpn_exporter-0.3.0/src/net/http/httptrace (from $GOPATH)
```

This is the main.go file:

```
package main

import (
        "flag"
        "github.com/kumina/openvpn_exporter/exporters"
        "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
        "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "strings"
)

func main() {
        var (
                listenAddress      = flag.String("web.listen-address", ":9176", "Address to listen on for web interface and telemetry.")
                metricsPath        = flag.String("web.telemetry-path", "/metrics", "Path under which to expose metrics.")
                openvpnStatusPaths = flag.String("openvpn.status_paths", "examples/client.status,examples/server2.status,examples/server3.status", "Paths at which OpenVPN places its status files.")
                ignoreIndividuals  = flag.Bool("ignore.individuals", false, "If ignoring metrics for individuals")
        )
        flag.Parse()

        log.Printf("Starting OpenVPN Exporter\n")
        log.Printf("Listen address: %v\n", *listenAddress)
        log.Printf("Metrics path: %v\n", *metricsPath)
        log.Printf("openvpn.status_path: %v\n", *openvpnStatusPaths)
        log.Printf("Ignore Individuals: %v\n", *ignoreIndividuals)

        exporter, err := exporters.NewOpenVPNExporter(strings.Split(*openvpnStatusPaths, ","), *ignoreIndividuals)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        prometheus.MustRegister(exporter)

        http.Handle(*metricsPath, promhttp.Handler())
        http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                w.Write([]byte(`
                        <html>
                        <head><title>OpenVPN Exporter</title></head>
                        <body>
                        <h1>OpenVPN Exporter</h1>
                        <p><a href='` + *metricsPath + `'>Metrics</a></p>
                        </body>
                        </html>`))
        })
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(*listenAddress, nil))
}
```

Comment: `go mod tidy` & `go mod download` & `go build -o openvpn_exporter main.go` AND switch building to some debian image (if you build in docker) or reinstall go (if you build natively)

Comment: it actually looks weird: `math/bits` and `net/http/httptrace` are build in pacakges. looks like you  need to reinstall go, but first try dockerized build.

Comment: Where did you download this from? Did it come with any installation instructions?

Comment: this is entrypoint to https://github.com/kumina/openvpn_exporter

Answer (score 0):

You have something wrong with your local go installation. I would suggest to re install go to the last version.

I was able to reproduce the installation of the exporter via Docker.

```
FROM golang:1.16.7-buster
RUN go get github.com/kumina/openvpn_exporter
RUN ls -la $GOPATH/bin
```

```sh
> DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build --no-cache -t butuzov/none .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   5.12kB
Step 1/3 : FROM golang:1.16.7-buster
1.16.7-buster: Pulling from library/golang
627b765e08d1: Already exists 
c040670e5e55: Already exists 
073a180f4992: Already exists 
bf76209566d0: Already exists 
6182a456504b: Already exists 
636ca4e39e2f: Already exists 
9bf36a081430: Already exists 
Digest: sha256:8e8910fa802194a30d5ebfbf3065d304e9e853ac50466c523be07ca657d9d6a1
Status: Downloaded newer image for golang:1.16.7-buster
 ---> 0821480a2b48
Step 2/3 : RUN go get github.com/kumina/openvpn_exporter
 ---> Running in f6b8b33eaedb
go: downloading github.com/kumina/openvpn_exporter v0.3.0
go: downloading github.com/prometheus/client_golang v0.9.1
go: downloading github.com/prometheus/common v0.0.0-20181020173914-7e9e6cabbd39
go: downloading github.com/prometheus/client_model v0.0.0-20180712105110-5c3871d89910
go: downloading github.com/golang/protobuf v1.2.0
go: downloading github.com/beorn7/perks v0.0.0-20180321164747-3a771d992973
go: downloading github.com/prometheus/procfs v0.0.0-20181005140218-185b4288413d
go: downloading github.com/matttproud/golang_protobuf_extensions v1.0.1
Removing intermediate container f6b8b33eaedb
 ---> 609cfb4b4638
Step 3/3 : RUN ls -la $GOPATH/bin
 ---> Running in 82ed751fa209
total 9332
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    4096 Aug 11 13:56 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    4096 Aug 11 13:56 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 9545202 Aug 11 13:56 openvpn_exporter
Removing intermediate container 82ed751fa209
 ---> a86de0dbc366
Successfully built a86de0dbc366
Successfully tagged butuzov/none:latest

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
```